# A unexpected behavior in RelationGraph

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, built-in-symbols

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

Firstly we get these idiom

```
web = Import["http://chengyu.t086.com/jielong/zuichang.html"];
idiom = StringCases[web, 
   RegularExpression[
    "(?<=\\s\\-\\>\\s)[一-龥]{4}|[一-龥]{4}(?=\\s\\-\\>\\s)"]];
```

Then he use the `RelationGraph` to draw graph.

```
g = RelationGraph[StringTake[#1, -1] == StringTake[#2, 1] &, 
  idiom[[;; 1664]]]
```

We can get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Actually the `idiom` have more element.

```
idiom // Length
```

> 1792

But If I want to get more long graph upto `1665`

```
g = RelationGraph[StringTake[#1, -1] == StringTake[#2, 1] &, 
      idiom[[;; 1665]]]
```

[image]

We'll get a unexpected graph or a error information,But I cannot find any bad stuff surround  1655

```
Take[idiom, {1663, 1667}]
```

> {依依不舍,舍己为人,轻而易举,举一反三,三生有幸}

Is it a bug of `RelationGraph` or have I missed something?

Comment: Regex tip: don't escape `-` and `>` to make your regex more readable. ;)

Comment: Interestingly, the problem seems to occur when both `1664` and `1665` are used in a list of at least 78 elements.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for your tip.And do you think this is a bug?

Comment: @Xavier Have you see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115940/a-unexpected-behaviour-of-relationgraph)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a duplicated vertex causing this issue:

```
idiom[[;; 1665]] // Length
```

> 1665

```
idiom[[;; 1665]] // Union // Length
```

> 1664

As a workaround, you could take Union over the vertex set:

```
g = RelationGraph[StringTake[#1, -1] == StringTake[#2, 1] &, 
   Union@idiom[[;; 1665]]];

GraphQ[g]
```

> True

but the output shouldn't be that.

You should report this to Wolfram support.

Comment: Thanks for you point out that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go ahead and call it a bug, but I don't know what is causing it (sadly, I'm not a kernel developer).  I can verify it's a bug below and I can offer a workaround to create the desired graph easily.

Here is a function that should create a `RelationGraph` but without the vertex labels, although I think that could be added easily enough,

```
bootstrapRelationGraph[func_, list_] := 
  Select[Tuples[Range@Length@list, 2], 
    func[list[[First@#]], list[[Last@#]]] &] // 
     (Graph[Flatten[{#1 -> #2} & @@@ #]] &);
```

We can test that it makes a graph equivalent to that from `RelationGraph`,

```
graph1 = bootstrapRelationGraph[
  StringTake[#1, -1] === StringTake[#2, 1] &, idiom[[37 ;; 125]]]
graph2 = RelationGraph[StringTake[#1, -1] === StringTake[#2, 1] &, 
  idiom[[37 ;; 125]]]
IsomorphicGraphQ[graph1, graph2]
```

[image]

Now the smallest sublist I found that reproduces the error is `{1664, 1665, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 1591}`, as seen below the bootstrapped version does not give the erroneous results.

```
graph1 = bootstrapRelationGraph[
  StringTake[#1, -1] === StringTake[#2, 1] &, 
  idiom[[{1664, 1665, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 
     1591}]]];
graph2 = RelationGraph[StringTake[#1, -1] === StringTake[#2, 1] &, 
  idiom[[{1664, 1665, 1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 
     1591}]]];
{graph1, graph2}
IsomorphicGraphQ[graph1, graph2]
```

[image]

As far as I can tell, that signals that there is some kind of bug in `RelationGraph`.  You can get the full graph easily enough by

```
bootstrapRelationGraph[
 StringTake[#1, -1] === StringTake[#2, 1] &, idiom]
```

[image]

### Edit

The simplest example I can find that reproduces this bug is

```
{RelationGraph[Last@#1 == First@#2 &, 
  Join[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, Partition[Range[4, 12], 2, 1]]],
 RelationGraph[Last@#1 == First@#2 &, 
  Join[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, Partition[Range[3, 11], 2, 1]]]}
```

[image]

So the bug has nothing to do with the Chinese character set and nothing to do with `String` functions.