# A unexpected behaviour of RelationGraph

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, built-in-symbols

```
$Version
```

> "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"

I want to match the based point of `VoronoiMesh`(`pts` in code) with its polygon(`poly` in code).This is my code

```
SeedRandom[2016526]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
Show[%, Graphics[{Orange, Point[pts]}]]
poly = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
```

[image]

When using the documentation of [`RelationGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html)'s first method:

```
RelationGraph[RegionMember[#2, #1] &, Join[pts, poly]]
```

We get a wrong result and a error information like

[image]

In this case,I can understand its error information but its wrong result.Then we try its second method in documentation.

```
RelationGraph[RegionMember[#2, #1] &, pts, poly]
```

We get some error information and the right result.Confuse me about it error informations like following

[image]

But I think I'm using this function in a right way.How to understand these phenomena?And when I use `Echo` to look this code's process

[image]

But as the documentation

[image]

I think shouldn't appear the elements of `pts` to be the parameter of `RegionMember` at the same time.This is a bug or I miss something?And how to adjust this code?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58395)?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your link.But this post is that I suspect a bug in `RelationGraph` :)

Comment: Yes, I only linked to it because there are easier ways to match points to their corresponding Voronoi cells.

Answer (score 3):

**Two argument form:**

> RelationGraph[f, {v1, v2, ...}] gives the graph with vertices vi and
>   edges from vi to vj whenever f[vi, vj] is True.

What's not stated is that there is a check that f[v1, v1] returns explicitly True or False. You can use `TrueQ` to ensure this, so for example this gives the correct result:

```
RelationGraph[TrueQ @ RegionMember[#2, #1] &, Join[pts, poly]]
```

Of course there are still warnings when RegionMember[point, polygon] is called.

**Three argument form:**

> RelationGraph[f, {v1, v2, ...}, {w1, w2, ...}] gives the graph with
>   vertices vi, wj and edges from vi to wj whenever f[vi, wj] is True.

If you check the internal code (for example with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[RelationGraph] ``) it is clear that the criterion is tested in both directions, f[vi, wj] and f[wj, vi]. So again there are warnings when RegionMember[point, polygon] is called. It's not clear if this is a bug or incomplete documentation.

**Workaround:**

In either case you can get the correct result without warnings by using a function that only calls `RegionMember` if the arguments are the right way round, and returns `False` otherwise.

```
rm[q_List, p_Polygon] := RegionMember[p, q]
rm[__] = False;

RelationGraph[rm, pts, poly]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you agree this is a bug?If you think so,I will add a bug title for the question.

Comment: @yode, I think it's more likely the intended behaviour, but not properly documented.

Comment: But I think [this sentence](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/04/02/58e0e4ce34f68.jpg) portray the behavior completely