# Why Mathematica introduced so many bug after version 10

Tags: version-10, version-11

Well, this post has nothing to do with code, but relate to *Mathematica*. This query is deep in my mind for so long time. But when I ask *Wolfram support*, I am always told some official words, which is not my expectation. I want to know the real truth.

Actually I have only used *Mathematica* for three years. But even so, I can feel the tendency that the next version will introduce more bugs and the current ones are hardly fixed. This is why many of my friends stay at version *9.0.1* still. Since I am able to get the tendency, users with more than *10* years' experience must also be. I will just give two examples here.

- The bug of `RelationGraph` is reported twice by myself, but [this
  bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115940/21532) persists.
- The bug of *Image-Tool*, which is very convenient to do some
  image-processing sometimes, is also reported twice by myself. But the
  bug is more serious in version *11.1*. These two GIFs demonstrate it completely. If
  we are in [11.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmiMU.gif) we will get
  some error messages but we can still get the mask . If we are in
  [11.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI4Vg.gif), we get nothing but that
  error window.

I don't have patience to report the same bug anymore. I hope this will not be regarded as a complaint, but a request to know why *Mathematica* has become like this. Why fewer bugs existed in the *core language* than before, but they surge after version *10.0*? Another funny thing I think of is, why *Wolfram Research* doesn't open a bug list, that can help customers know the fixed situation and prevents them from submitting a repetitive bug report. It's a win-win choice. And as I know, *Dr. Wolfram* is also a heavy *Mathematica* user. Why can he bear those bugs? Can any insiders tell me something?

Comment: To those vote to close:Do this question is not suitable in *Mathematica.SE*?

Comment: [Here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/900782) is the good comment: "A software company I worked for years ago had a triage policy about bugs. Some were so critical they were fixed immediately. Less critical ones were fixed in the next release. Some were regarded as being sufficiently insignificant that they were never fixed. I don't know Wolfram Research's policy but I suspect it is similar."

Comment: I voted to close because I think any answers to this question will be entirely opinion-based.

Comment: @Cassini 1.The customer can know truth.2.The *WR* should know the seriousness of the problem

Comment: @andre: Huh?  What does that have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: I think that the larger a program gets the more bugs. If the emphasis is on still more expansion, then there is less time for fixing them. Someone over there at Wolfram has a very fertile imagination and wants to expand in all directions at once. This I would imagine, places a huge burden on those who actually have the job of implementing those ideas. More new stuff, less time to clean up the old. Like with everything else, you have to work around the bugs.

Comment: @bobbym As I know,the *Matlab* is a big program,but fewer bug..

Comment: Use new versions for new features. Use point releases to fix bugs. And take bugs seriously.

Comment: Could you reframe this and make it viable by calling for an analysis of MSE to maybe produce the facts to the story? E.g. couldnˋt the bug tags and headers here be used to give a bugsadded-bugsfixed chart for the Versions? That would be interesting. Otherwise I think this should be moved to chat.

Comment: Would be interesting to see some data about the number of bugs. I guess they are growing much slower than the number of functions (although some of them implement simple stuff and have bad performance). Furthermore a comparison with other programming languages or some general relationships would be interesting.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Could you tell me something?Especially about that *Image-Tool*,that is very practical,but it is disable totally in 11.1

Comment: I do agree that this is off topic, regardless of whether or not the OP's frustration is warranted.  Perhaps Wolfram Community is a better place for it.  Those who are voting to reopen: do you have any reasoning that is better than that you are frustrated with bugs? I am too, but that does not make this a pratical answerable question.  It is not a question.  It is a complaint.

Comment: @Szabolcs question off topic: yes, but not a complaint. I think that the OP is really looking for informations. I will not vote to reopen the question

Comment: FWIW, for the bug cited/linked in the OP, one can return to the V9 behavior by executing `Unprotect[RelationGraph]; Remove[RelationGraph];` :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Of course,and if you are willing to uninstall *Mathematica*,then your computer have no bug anymore.Just a joke. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience is different. As new versions come out, I think two things happen:

1. Bugs in earlier versions generally (but not always) get fixed. In this sense, as time goes on, the number of bugs **decreases**, and Mma gets better and better with time.
2. New functions are introduced. And when functions are new, there are always issues and quirks that need to get resolved (which is why Space Shuttles blow up). And in recent years, the number of new functions added has been staggering. In this sense, Mma is also getting better with time, but given so many new functions, it would not be surprising if issues pop up that need to be resolved.

I certainly don't mean to defend bugs - I find them irksome and irritating, especially when my existing code or notebooks don't function correctly. But fixing them can also be very time consuming -- and fixing one thing can cause other things to break. If the bug is in some specialised code, there may also be personnel issues, where one person coded up some area of functionality, leaves the company, and finding someone else to work through the original person's code cannot be fun.

Comment: I think there is an important third case, especially in Mathematica: functions are changed, either generalized or optimized. These cases are the ones where sometimes bugs are introduced which are especially irritating to users...